# Rails 4: Is it necessary to explicitly enable Sprockets for Asset Pipeline?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I'm new to rails. I'm working on including javascript and css files in the application I'm building. I have `//= require_tree` . in my `application.js`. I put 3rd party javascript files under `vendor/assets/javascripts`, as well as my own javascript files in `app/assets/javascripts`. I also included 3rd party and my own CSS files in the proper places. I expected rails to combine all the javascript files into one file and all the CSS files into another file. Instead, the head section of my pages contain separate link and script tags for each of the files I included. Do I need to explicitly enable Sprockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I needed to set an option to **false** in config/environments/development.rb.

```
# Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
# This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
# number of complex assets.
config.assets.debug = false
```

Now asset concatenation is working for me.